# A simple Thread scenario in Java where the Runnable interface need not be implemented by the Thread implementing class

Tags: java

Let's look at the following code, it's working exactly.

```
final class DemoThread
{
    public void temp()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println( "Isn't it great ?" ) ;
            }
        } ) .start() ;
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        new DemoThread().temp();
    }
}
```

It works fine and displays the message *Isn't it great ?* on the console. The only question here is that why the Runnable interface need not be implemented by the class **DemoThread**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Runnable` is being implemented by the [anonymous inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) within the `temp` method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println( "Isn't it great ?" ) ;
    }
} ) .start() ;
```

Given that an instance of `DemoThread` *isn't* being passed into the `Thread` constructor, whether or not it implements `Runnable` is completely orthogonal to how the thread runs.

Your code is a similar to this:

```
final class DemoThread
{
    public void temp()
    {
        new Thread(new Anonymous()).start();
    }

    private class Anonymous implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println( "Isn't it great ?" ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Does that make it clearer for you?

Answer (score 3):

`DemoThread` is not actually doing anything with the `Thread` itself. It's spawning a new `Thread` which is wrapped around an anonymous class that implements `Runnable`.

```
new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println( "Isn't it great ?" ) ;
    }
}
```

Creates a new class. You'll see it in the file system when javac is run.

Answer (score 2):

What must implement the Runnable interface is the object you pass as a parameter to the Thread object, which is what's going to be executed.

In your case, you've already declared an anonymous class which implements Runnable, which is the one passed to the Thread object.

```
new Thread(new Runnable()   // <--- This is the class that's implementing Runnable
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println( "Isn't it great ?" ) ;
            }
        } ) .start() ;
```